# How to freeze a file for changes but leave it in the repository using Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Quite often I have a situation like the following:

- some Hg repository with a bunch of configuration files that are shared
- some configuration files contain passwords, that should not be shared, they are local to the user

I would like to keep a version history on these files, but they will only occasionally be updated. It is annoying if every time you do a commit or merge or update you have to remember that you do *not* want to commit your locally changed password.

How can I freeze a file in the repository (and conversely, for the occasional legitimate update, unfreeze it) so that it does not appear in the commit list, but does appear as versioned in the repository and everyone can share a base copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-X` option for commit, none (easy) for merge

```
-X --exclude PATTERN [+] exclude names matching the given patterns
```

i.e most times you commit `hg ci -X FILENAME`, sometimes - pure `hg ci`. You can define `hg ci -X FILENAME` as new alias and use two different commands for different commits

In case of merges you can try to define for config-file special [merge-tool](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) (provably [internal:local or internal:fail](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/merge-tools))

Anyway, you selected wrong and error-prone method of storing *local* configs as shared common files. (Viable) alternatives may include (in order to name a few)

- Config.TEMPLATE in repository and modified for local needs hgignore'd Config
- [LocalBranch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LocalbranchExtension), in which you store code with location-specific changes
- [MQ extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) (somehow related to 1-st solution) - repository stored "vanilla" config, all local-only changes placed in MQ-patch

Comment: We use MQ, but I think we'll go with the template approach, or some version of it at least.

Answer (score 3):

This question gets asked a lot, and the answer is always the same: there's no good way to do what you want.  A file that's tracked is tracked for all changes.

The setup everyone settles on is committing a configurationfile.example to the repo where changes everyone needs are shared, and add configurationfile to your ignore.  If you're savvy you then have your launch script copy configurationfile.example to configuration location if it doesn't already exists.  If your configuration format is flexible enough to support an include (most are these days) you have you configurationfile committed and have it do an include of a non-tracked (ignored) configurationfile.local where people override things.  This is how everyone does it in both git and Mercurial.

Comment: This particular configuration does not support local vs default settings files, but it is easy enough to create a pre-build step of some kind to do a merge of local settings into placeholder settings of a config file, which is probably the easiest way to go here.

Comment: Yeah, if you're lucky it's got well defined semantics about whether later settings override earlier ones or are ignored, which let's you do `cat settings.global settings.local >| settings` before each run.